# Why does that every time after I update Android studio, it ask me to update build tool too?

Tags: android, android-studio, build-tools

As title, why does that every time after I update Android studio, it ask me to update build tool too? I did not change any of the file in the android project. In my build.gradle, buildToolSdkVersion is still the same before updating Android studio, why should I update build tool? Thanks.